# Convert WSDL into java using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsdl

I want to convert a WSDL file into java code using IntelliJ but when I use 'generate java code from wsdl' and click ok button, an error shows up. The error says NoClassDefFoundError. The webservice is websphere.

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error message.

Comment: Java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com/sun/tools/internal/ws/wsimport exception in thread "main"

Comment: Which exactly JDK version are you using for your project?

Comment: I use Jdk1.6.0 for my project

Comment: If you are using maven, you could consider using the jabx maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did google for jaxb plugin (i think that you meant jaxb) but i did not find a download link for the plugin to download and i do not know how to use it. Thanks a lot.